# Why my BrowserComponent shows with small width?

Tags: codenameone

I am having a BrowserComponent inside a Container. This Container is add then into a tab. The BrowserComponent is showing html either from url or from local storage.
On simulator it seems ok but on an Iphone it is showing with a very small width.

Below is the code for the Container which is added to the Tab and into which I place the BrowserComponent.

```
public class MemberDetail extends Container {

       // private Form MembersList = null;
       public MemberDetail( String dataUri, Form MembersList) throws IOException {
            BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
            if ( dataUri.startsWith("http") ) {
               browser.setURL( dataUri );
            }
            else {
                String html = Util.readToString( Storage.getInstance().createInputStream( dataUri ) );

              browser.setPage( html , "/");
            }
            browser.getUnselectedStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
            browser.getPressedStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
            browser.getDisabledStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);

            this.add( browser );
       }     
}
```

and this is the code for the Tab

```
public MemberGui(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance, String companyName, String logo, String profile, String actions, String galleryUrl, Form membersList) {
        try {
            this.membersList = membersList;
            initGuiBuilderComponents(resourceObjectInstance);
            Image imLogo = EncodedImage.create( Storage.getInstance().createInputStream( logo ) );
            if ( imLogo != null) {
                this.gui_Label_Logo.setIcon( imLogo );
            }
            Style s = this.createStyle();

            this.gui_Border_MemberDetails.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,  this.getTab(profile, actions, galleryUrl, membersList, s ));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e( ex);
        }
    }

 private Tabs getTab( String profile, String action, String galleryUrl,  Form membersList, Style s) {
            Tabs t = new Tabs();
             try {

                t.addTab("Η εταιρεία", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME,s) , new MemberDetail( profile, membersList ) );
                if ( action != "") {
                    t.addTab("Δράση", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PIN_DROP,s), new MemberDetail( action, membersList ) );
                }
                if ( galleryUrl != "") {
                    t.addTab("Φωτογραφίες", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_COLLECTIONS,s), new MemberDetail( galleryUrl, membersList )  );
                }
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Log.e(ex);
           }
            return t;
        }

         private Style createStyle()
        {
            Style s = new Style();
            s.setBorder( Border.createLineBorder(1, 000000) );
            s.setAlignment( CENTER );
            return s;
        }
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MemberDetail` has the default layout which is `FlowLayout`. `FlowLayout` gives components their natural size (preferred size).

The preferred size of the HTML is unreliable as it takes a while for the HTML to load. Anyway the solution is simple. Place the browser component in a layout location that determines its size, specifically in the center of a border layout or something like this.